# parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data 200 OK

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to populate a jqGrid loading data from a MySQL table named Users.
The js script looks like this:

jQUERY script

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'users_grid_load_data.php?q=2', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",           
        colNames:['Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username','Level'], 
        colModel:[ 
             {name:'id_user',index:'id_user', width:55}, 
             {name:'firstname',index:'firstname', width:90}, 
             {name:'lastname',index:'lastname', width:90}, 
             {name:'username',index:'username', width:90},
             {name:'level',index:'level', width:80, align:"right"}       
        ], 
        rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30], 
        pager: '#pager2', 
        sortname: 'id_user', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "asc", 
        height:"auto",
        width:"auto",
        caption:"LIST OF USERS" 
    }); 
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
```

Now this is the users_grid_load_data.php file:

```
$page = $_GET['page']; 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

$count = $row['count']; 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
      $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
      $total_pages = 0; 
} 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = $mysqli->query( $SQL ); 

$i=0;
$responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page; 
$responce->total = $total_pages; 
$responce->records = $count;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id_user'];
   $responce->rows[$i]'cell']=
              array($row['id_user'],$row['firstname'],
                    $row['lastname'],$row['username'],$row['level']);
   $i++;
}

echo json_encode($responce);
```

The jqGrid is loaded but in its middle shows the message:

```
parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data 200 OK {"page":"1","total":1,"records":"1","rows":[{"id":"4","cell":["4","Alexandre","Araujo","alexaraujo73","2"]}]}
```

I can see the register loaded from the MySQL table users but I got stuck in this error.
Can anybody help me? I really appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "total": 1 Missing "s maybe?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Missing `[` before `'cell']`: `$responce->rows[$i]'cell']=`

Comment: You may be emitting two JSON documents instead of one.

Comment: @Andreas it was a typo otherwise he will not get JSON data from server side.

Comment: It was a typo @Andreas. In the code it is right.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @tadman! About emitting two JSON documents instead of one, I didn't understand what you're saying. Sorry.

Comment: A `JSON.parse` call will fail if you have two lines of data, each of which contains a separate JSON dump. That's why it's odd that error is on "line 2", it's probably a second `{...}` document, which is technically invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of undefined error of any variable. From your code you are creating a response variable named as `$responce` and in `while loop` you are using a property `rows` which is not defined previously, so try to declare it before using like,

```
$responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page; 
$responce->total = $total_pages; 
$responce->records = $count;
$responce->rows=array();// create an array of rows here
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $arr = array('id'=>$row['id_user'],'cell'=>array($row['id_user'],
                                     $row['firstname'],
                                     $row['lastname'],
                                     $row['username'],
                                     $row['level']) // cell closing
          ); // closing of arr
   $responce->rows[]=$arr; // push it to $rows of $reponce
   //$i++; // no need of it
}
```

As you are sending JSON data to jqgrid, so your response must be json and nothing else. To prevent others errors added in response use [error_reporting()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) like,

```
// hide all notice/warnings
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: _"To prevent errors..."_ because if I don't see an error then there will be no error...

Comment: It was just for production version and for development version he can enable it.

Comment: I've tried your tips but still getting the same error @Rohan Kumar